# CouchDB / PouchDB mango query: has in array

Tags: couchdb, pouchdb

Is it possible with mango query to find those documents, which have a provided string in an array field?

Say,

```
const doc = {
  _id: 'testdoc',
  tags: ['pouch', 'couch', 'mysql'],
}

$db.find({ selector: {
  tags: {
    $has: 'pouch' // what goes here?
  } 
}})
```

Answer (score 5):

You have to use the $elemMatch operator

```
{
  selector: {
    tags: {
      "$elemMatch": { $eq: "pouch" }
    }
  }
}
```

For further documentation, head [here](http://docs.couchdb.org/en/2.1.0/api/database/find.html)

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll give it a try. The definition of this operator in the docs is so confusing to me, that I decided it does the opposite :)

Comment: for me, this worked `tags: {
        $elemMatch: { $eq: 'pouch'}
      }`